# Transferring files from iOS 15 devices with Ubuntu + Fuse + libimobiledevice / ifuse?

Tags: 20.04, iphone, itunes, fuse, ios

Anyone have 20.04+ working with [FUSE](https://github.com/libfuse/) + [libimobiledevice/iFuse](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse) working with iOS 15.x to transfer files from an iPhone/iPad to Ubuntu?

If so, any particular instructions you followed to make it work?

Comment: Does it have to be over USB? Or would transferring files over a network connection be an option?

Comment: @matigo network connection is fine at this point. Anything to get the functionality back.

Comment: what you do exactly and what happens, and what you expect?

Comment: The most consistent solution I’ve found that works across all recent iOS updates is to have a Samba share on Ubuntu, then copy files from the phone using the Files application (which can “Connect to server”) 

Comment: @matigo this is an interesting suggestion, but I do not see "Voice Memos" in `Files → On My iOS Device` or otherwise... Is this somewhere I'm missing or is there a way to enable this that I'm missing?